# Extracting XML document

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to pull out data from a XML Column in a table and realized I won't ever be able to find things very well as the formatting contains &lt and other characters. I've since converted the document into a nvarchar variable so that I can perform my own lookups via searching as text.

I've cobbled this together (badly, I'm sorry) and I'm now thinking I may have been better to use a tmp table but anyway.

I've realised I'm not capturing per record of @profilename because of the TOP 1 being used but would like too and for it to appear in the main select body on a per record basis but I'm a bit lost...

```
DECLARE @LOGGING AS nvarchar(10)
DECLARE @Profilename nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @configxml_vchar nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @configxml XML
SET @Profilename = NULL
SET @LOGGING = 'low'
SET @configxml = (Select TOP 1 configxml from dirsyncpro.dbo.bt_config ) ----where bt_config_pk = 5
SET @configxml_vchar = (select cast(@configxml as nvarchar(max)))
SET @profilename = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@configxml_vchar, CHARINDEX('SyncName', @configxml_vchar)
, CHARINDEX('/SyncName',@configxml_vchar) - CHARINDEX('SyncName', @configxml_vchar) + Len('/SyncName')))
select @Profilename AS ProfileName, BT_Config_PK AS ProfileID, LastModified, ConfigXML, @LOGGING AS LogLevel from DirSyncPro.dbo.BT_Config where configxml.exist('//*/text()[contains(upper-case(.),upper-case("LoggingLevel&gt;low&lt;/LoggingLevel"))]') = 1
```

I'm looking for a select within a select I imagine but can't place where it should go or how to format it...

I appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: Thank you. I've done this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with the below.... There was a schema, I just failed to use it.

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES
('http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BinaryTree.DirSync.Common' AS ns) SELECT BT_Config_PK AS ConfigID, CONVERT(XML, C.ConfigXML.value('(/)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')).value('(/ns:DirSyncProfile/ns:SyncName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS ProfileName, CONVERT(XML, C.ConfigXML.value('(/)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')).value('(/ns:DirSyncProfile/ns:Common/ns:LoggingLevel)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS LoggingLevel FROM BT_Config AS C
```